# showing/hiding content is not working in JQuery/CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

my JQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.both').click(function (event){
        $("#cl").fadeOut().removeClass("showTemp").addClass("showTempH");
        $("#nc").fadeOut().removeClass("showTemp").addClass("showTempH");
        $("#bth").fadeIn().removeClass("showTempH").addClass("showTemp");
        $(".both").removeClass("demo").addClass("active");
        $(".clinical").removeClass("active").addClass("demo");
        $(".nonclinical").removeClass("active").addClass("demo");
    });
    $('.clinical').click(function (event){
        $("#cl").fadeIn().removeClass("showTempH").addClass("showTemp");
        $("#nc").fadeOut().removeClass("showTemp").addClass("showTempH");
        $("#bth").fadeOut().removeClass("showTemp").addClass("showTempH");
        $(".both").removeClass("active").addClass("demo");
        $(".clinical").removeClass("demo").addClass("active");
        $(".nonclinical").removeClass("active").addClass("demo");
    });
    $('.nonclinical').click(function (event){
        $("#cl").fadeOut().removeClass("showTemp").addClass("showTempH");
        $("#nc").fadeIn().removeClass("showTempH").addClass("showTemp");
        $("#bth").fadeOut().removeClass("showTemp").addClass("showTempH");
        $(".both").removeClass("active").addClass("demo");
        $(".clinical").removeClass("active").addClass("demo");
        $(".nonclinical").removeClass("demo").addClass("active");
    });

});
```

My CSS code:

```
.demo {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block; /* Change anchor to block element */
    width: 195px; height: 37px; /* Specify width and height of the image. Height is value of each individual button graphic */
    background-image: url(theImages/inactive.png); /* Add the image as a background */
    background-position: top; /* Set the position to the top */
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 37px;       /* the same as your div height */
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FCFCFC;
}
.demo:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.active {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block; /* Change anchor to block element */
    width: 195px; height: 37px; /* Specify width and height of the image. Height is value of each individual button graphic */
    background-image: url(theImages/active.png); /* Add the image as a background */
    background-position: top; /* Set the position to the top */
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 37px;       /* the same as your div height */
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.active:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.showTemp {
    color: #1D2F9F;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Verdana, 'Source Sans Pro';
    font-weight: plain;
}
.showTempH {
    color: #1D2F9F;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Verdana, 'Source Sans Pro';
    font-weight: plain;
    display: none;
}
```

My HTML code:

```
                <table border=1 cellPadding=0 cellSpacing=0 width=100%>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=33%><div class="active both">BOTH</div></td>
                        <td width=33%><div class="demo clinical">CLINICAL</div></td>
                        <td width=33%><div class="demo nonclinical">NON-CLINICAL</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <ul id="bth" class=showTemp>
                                <li>Mission Statement - Interfaith Medical Center</li>
                                <li>About Employee Health Services</li>
                                <li>National Patient Safety Goals</li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <ul id="cl" class=showTempH>
                                <li>Pain Assessment and Management</li>
                                <li>Medication Errors</li>
                                <li>Bioethic Consultation Process</li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <ul id="nc" class=showTempH>
                                <li>Emergency Management</li>
                                <li>Infection Control</li>
                                <li>The Environment of Care Program</li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

What i am looking to do is depending on the button the user clicks, that button has the ACTIVE class and the rest two will have the DEMO class. how do i modify my existing jquery script?

Current output: [Current output site](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/test.php)

Comment: You should describe what happens now and how it is deviating from what the end result should be as well.

Comment: website added to the question and also heres a link: http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/test.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all id attributes must be unique. You can't have multiple elements with same id.

```
<td width=33%>
    <div class="active both">BOTH</div>
</td>
<td width=33%>
    <div class="demo clinical">CLINICAL</div>
</td>
<td width=33%>
    <div class="demo nonclinical">NON-CLINICAL</div>
</td>
```

And you need an event listener that will handle all three buttons click,

```
$(".demo").live("click", function() {
       $(".active").removeClass("active").addClass("demo");
       $(this).removeClass("demo").addClass("active");
 });
```

And here is a demo page.

http://jsfiddle.net/JRcyd/2

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I update my question with all the recommendations. One thing I am still looking to do is make the Jquery code more effecient.

Comment: I wish i can choose all of them as best answer... except this one did the trick. THANKS!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

IDs need to be unique. You can't have two elements with `id="demo"`. Use classes instead.

Change:

```
<tr>
    <td width=33%><div id="active" class=both>BOTH</div></td>
    <td width=33%><div id="demo" class=clinical>CLINICAL</div></td>
    <td width=33%><div id="demo" class=nonclinical>NON-CLINICAL</div></td>
</tr>
```

To:

```
<tr>
    <td width=33%><div class="active, both">BOTH</div></td>
    <td width=33%><div class="demo, clinical">CLINICAL</div></td>
    <td width=33%><div class="demo, nonclinical">NON-CLINICAL</div></td>
</tr>
```

Then change your `#demo` and `#active` references to `.demo` and `.active`.

As for the issue at hand:

> What i am looking to do is depending on the button the user clicks, that button has the ACTIVE class and the rest two will have the DEMO class. how do i modify my existing jquery script?

You currently aren't setting these classes, you'd use:

```
$('.active').click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('demo');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

> How would I incorporate the fade in and fade out of the contents with ur Jquery code?

You could use the `showTemp` and `showTempH` classes you currently have in place:

```
$('.active').click(function() {
    var $current = $('.showTempH');

    $('.showTemp').fadeOut().removeClass('showTemp').addClass('showTempH');
    $current.fadeIn().removeClass('showTempH').addClass('showTemp');

    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('demo');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Comment: Thanks, was thinking of doing it but you gave me the convincing i needed.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include what I assume to be a solution to your question.

Comment: I've added a possible way of doing that to my answer now. I haven't tested it, mind you...

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I update my question with all the recommendations. One thing I am still looking to do is make the Jquery code more effecient.

Comment: i think your will work and you can visit the link i provided. It fades in two of the other DIV.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the classes after the fadeout / fadein so you need to do something like this

```
$("#cl").fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("showTemp").addClass("showTempH");
});
```

to add the active class to the button that was clicked, first add a common class to all your buttons, then you will need to change active and demo into classes (ids should be unique) in the css (`.active` instead of `#active`) and then in your button click you can add

```
$('.commonButtonClass').removeClass('active').addClass('demo');
$(this).addClass('active').removeClass('demo');
```

Comment: What is wrong with the current script? It is doing what it is meant to do, except the blue button is not changing to the DEMO class.

Comment: the way you have done it means the classes could be added and removed bfore the fadein and fadeout have finished.  By changing it to fire in the function in means the fadein and out will have completed before changing the class

Comment: Can i make it so instead of making three separate code one single block of code will take care of all three buttons? it will save filesize space?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I update my question with all the recommendations. One thing I am still looking to do is make the Jquery code more effecient.